# Adding foreignkey to model_to_dict - Django 1.11

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this method, which saves a parent model fields into 2 child models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk and self.__class__.__name__ == 'Parent':
        Child1.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
        Child2.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But, on `Parent` model I have a field like:

```
    team_lead = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    verbose_name=_('decision team lead'),
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    null=True, blank=True
)
```

Whenever I try to save the parent it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\KKOCI\ifa_kkoci\new_ifa\IfA\ifa_standards_rms\apps\tlevels\views.py", line 26, in get_wireframe
form.save()
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 468, in save
self.instance.save()
File "C:\Users\KKOCI\ifa_kkoci\new_ifa\IfA\ifa_standards_rms\apps\tlevels\models.py", line 176, in save
TLevelsDraft.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 555, in __init__
_setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 216, in __set__
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "TLevelsDraft.team_lead" must be a "User" instance.
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /tlevels/wireframe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\KKOCI\ifa_kkoci\new_ifa\IfA\ifa_standards_rms\apps\tlevels\views.py", line 26, in get_wireframe
form.save()
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 468, in save
self.instance.save()
File "C:\Users\KKOCI\ifa_kkoci\new_ifa\IfA\ifa_standards_rms\apps\tlevels\models.py", line 176, in save
TLevelsDraft.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 555, in __init__
_setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
File "C:\ifavirtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 216, in __set__
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "TLevelsDraft.team_lead" must be a "User" instance.
"POST /tlevels/wireframe HTTP/1.1" 500 123932
```

Essentially `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "TLevelsDraft.team_lead" must be a "User" instance.` , of course, because the user selected on the parent model form, has 1 as id, so, how can I pass the fields in this case?

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't understand what you are doing here. Why are you trying to create an item using a dictionary representation of the existing item? Why have three copies of the same data?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm trying to save data from parent class into two child classes, it has to have a copy of the data on both child classes

Answer (score 1):

please change the key `TLevelsDraft.team_lead` to `TLevelsDraft.team_lead_id` in that dict returns from the  `model_to_dict(self)`

or directly  assign the user instance corresponding to that id